# Tension in string question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

> Problem: A 12.0-kg box resting on a horizontal, frictionless surface is attached to a 5.00-kg weight by a thin, light wire that passes without slippage over a frictionless pulley (the figure (Figure 1). The pulley has the shape of a uniform solid disk of mass 2.10 kg and diameter 0.520 m.
>
> [image: Problem]
>
> What are the horizontal and vertical tensions?
> The answers are:
> $T_h = 32.6\:\mathrm N$, $T_v = 35.4\:\mathrm N$.
>
> Complete guide to problem is [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071119110406AAM0VNE).

1. I don't understand why the tensions are different. For a rope, isn't the tension uniform?
2. Can you also explain why using $F_\mathrm{net} = (m_1+m_2)a$ wouldn't work here? $a$ would turn out different if I did this.
3. Also, why wouldn't you add the moment of inertia provided by the mass to the pulley moment of inertia? I remember doing a problem where you had to account for the added the $I$ of objects.

Comment: If the tensions weren't different, what would the net torque on the pulley be?

Comment: So there has to be a net torque for the pulley to move - is that what you're saying? --> Th-Tv=Ialpha. So the difference in tension goes into the rotation...

Comment: Yes. The vertical force is accelerating both the 12kg block and the pulley while the horizontal force is just accelerating the 12kg block.

Answer (score 1):

1. some of the tension goes into accelerating the pulley rotationally. Specifically $\Delta T \;R = I \frac{ \dot{v}}{R}$
2. Again you have to account for the mass moment of inertia of the disk. You could write $F_{net} = (m_1+m_2+\frac{I}{R^2}) a$
3. The masses do not rotate so their mass moment of inertia is of no use.